# How to debug a Windows Phone app?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

I am making an Ionic app but I am having trouble getting a Windows 10 version working. I have opened the Visual Studio project file and installed the app onto my device using the 'Debug' button, and this works OK. There are no errors displayed and the app works fine.

However, if I disconnect my phone and try loading the app when it's not in debug mode, the app crashes at the splash screen. I have tried using the `Debug > Debug Installed App Package` window in Visual Studio, but when I try to connect to my phone I get the error:

`Debugging on a Windows Phone device is not supported using Debug Installed App Package`

Is there another way to debug the app while it's loading to see why it's crashing? If not, how do I access error logs for the app? I have enabled crash dumps in the device's developer options but I'm not sure where they get saved to.

Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S. The device is a Windows Lumia 650 if that helps.

Comment: connect phone via USb to dev device, select debug/ARM and **target** to device in toolbar, press F5 (now app is deployed to phone in debug mode) and you can step through code.

Comment: Is the phone in developer mode